# Python 3: formatted str: get the sign of a number - without the number

Tags: python-3.x, formatting, sign

So, I know how to get number as a string with it's sign using

```py
    f'{my_num:+}'
```

But how do I get **just the sign** of a number as a string, using the new formatting syntax?

I really don't want to have to do ...

```py
    f"{'+' if my_num >= 0 else '-'}"
```

.. but maybe that's pythonic?

I found a much better alternative.. but is there really not an easier option?

```py
    f'{f"{my_num:+}"[:1]}'
```

Comment: I don't think you can get *just* the sign directly in string formatting, but it's easy enough with e.g. `"-" if my_num < 0 else "+"`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The answer box is below.  Comments on the question post are for asking for details or clarifications of the problem, not for posting answers.

Comment: @AJNeufeld comments on the question post are for asking for details or clarifications of the problem, not for hassling other users.